# How can I make any icon on the Mac dock bounce?

Tags: macos

I would like to be able to make an app's icon on the dock, for any application, bounce with a keyboard command. Is there any way I can do this?

It would need to work on all application icons, so for example which ever application is currently in use, the keyboard command would make that icon bounce like it does when the application is opening - although preferably it could bounce just once.

I presume some sort of script?

Thanks

Comment: This will actually be a fairly involved task, as there is no public API to make an arbitrary dock icon bounce.

Comment: right ok, so is it pretty much out of the question then?

Comment: Unless you want to go through mach_inject/mach_override, which I haven't gone in a few years and I'm not sure how many gotchas there are these days.